# Value Change listener not working in primefaces calendar

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.2 and JSF 2.0

My scenario is I have file date, last date and next date in my form.
When user enters file date I need to update file date value in bean so it's value can be used as minimum date in last date of attribute mindate and so in next date selection.

As per my knowledge value change listener can execute at form submission so I can not use it. I have used **p:ajax**. But still I am not able to set file date. As file date is not set it allows user to select last date and next date before date of file date.

**caseMaster.xhtml**

```
<p:calendar value="#{caseUitility.caseMaster.fileDate}" id="fileDate" effect="fadeIn" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" readOnlyInputText="true">
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{caseUitility.dateChange}"/>
</p:calendar>

<p:calendar value="#{caseUitility.caseMaster.lastDate}" required="true" id="lastDate" effect="fadeIn" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" readOnlyInputText="true" mindate="#{caseUitility.caseMaster.fileDate}" >
</p:calendar>
```

**CaseUitility.java**

```
public void dateChange(ActionEvent ae) {
    System.out.println("File Date: " + caseMaster.getFileDate());
    System.out.println("Hello... I am in DateChange");
}
```

can any guide me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In more recent versions of PrimeFaces, **`SelectEvent`** should be usedsee the following code snippet

```
<p:calendar id="event" value="#{calendarView.date4}">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{calendarView.onDateSelect}" update="msgs" />
</p:calendar>
```

```
public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Date Selected", format.format(event.getObject())));
}
```

*In older primefaces versions use **`DateSelectEvent`***

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{caseUitility.dateChange}"/>
```

```
public void dateChange(DateSelectEvent event) {
    Date date = event.getDate();
    System.out.println("File Date: " + date);
    System.out.println("Hello... I am in DateChange");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Daniel....You saved my half a day....once again thanks. Can you tell me how can I know/learn about ajax events for different kind of components. As primefaces not providing any help regarding events.

Comment: You are welcome, primefaces do provide all the information that you need , its in their User's Guide : http://primefaces.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 18):

You should add an update to your p:ajax. I had problems when selecting a date with the datepicker and when manually typing it in the field. The change event was not triggerd both ways. Therefore I used an p:ajax and a f:ajax with different events.

```
<p:calendar value="#{caseUitility.caseMaster.fileDate}" id="fileDate" effect="fadeIn" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" readOnlyInputText="true">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{caseUitility.dateSelect}" update="lastDate"/>
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="lastDate" listener="#{caseUitility.dateChange}"/>
</p:calendar>
```

And in the bean

```
public void dateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {
    caseMaster.setFileDate(event.getDate());
    System.out.println("File Date: " + caseMaster.getFileDate());
    System.out.println("Hello... I am in DateChange");
}

public void dateChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws MWSException {
    System.out.println("File Date: " + caseMaster.getFileDate());
    System.out.println("Hello... I am in DateChange");
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What is the reason for the use of 2 different ajax tags, one p:ajax and one f:ajax. Why not both p:ajax ?

Comment: @Chris, from what he said, I'm guessing that <p:ajax event="dateSelect" .../> covers the user clicking on the calendar and selecting a date, but not when changing the date by changing the text.  In that case, <f:ajax event="change" .../> covers the case where the user manually changes the text in the text field.

Comment: @pixelstix true

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{caseUitility.dateChange}"/>
```

And in the bean:

```
public void dateChange(SelectEvent event) 
{   
      date = (Date)event.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must consider doing this:

```
<p:calendar id="fileDate" value="#{caseUitility.caseMaster.fileDate}" navigator="true" effect="slideDown" mindate="#{caseUitility.today}" readOnlyInputText="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" required="true"  showOn="button" autocomplete="false">
    <p:ajax event="focus" listener="#{caseUitility.dateChange}" update="lastDate" />
</p:calendar>

public void dateChange()  {
     System.out.println("File Date: " + caseMaster.getFileDate());
}
```

If you use the "focus" event, it will be triggered on change or dateSelect for calendar primefaces control.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax event as dateSelect
like

```
<p:calendar value="#{caseUitility.caseMaster.fileDate}" id="fileDate" effect="fadeIn" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" readOnlyInputText="true">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="@this" update="lastDate" listener="#{caseUitility.dateChange}"/>
</p:calendar>   
<p:calendar value="#{caseUitility.caseMaster.lastDate}" required="true" id="lastDate" effect="fadeIn" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" readOnlyInputText="true" mindate="#{caseUitility.caseMaster.fileDate}" >
</p:calendar>
```

Listener,

```
public void dateChange(SelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("File Date: " + (Date) event.getObject());
    System.out.println("Hello... I am in DateChange");
}
```

but keep in mind that, you should not use any other component id in process (means only @this is allowed in process) otherwise listener will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onstart` and `oncomplete` (does not appear in primefaces doc).

I solved with that:

```
<p:calendar
      id="fromDate"
      value="#{reportBean.fromDate}"
      pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
      locale="es"
      maxdate="#{reportBean.untilDate}">
      <p:ajax event="dateSelect" 
          onstart="openModal();" 
          oncomplete="closeModal();"  
          update="untilDate div_report"/>
</p:calendar>
```

Javascript:

```
function openModal(){
    $('#mdlLoading').modal('open');
}
function closeModal(){
    $('#mdlLoading').modal('close');
}
```

Hope this help someone!