# How to retrieve a value from XHTML in my bean using <p:ajax> on primefaces?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, listener

2.8 and Primefaces 6.0 And i want to retrieve the value of a date from my xhtml to make specific treatments Before submitting my form.

But the value of the date is always null in the bean Before submitting.

Here is my XHTML

```
                            <p:outputLabel for="dateDebut" value="Date Debut"/>
                        <p:calendar id="dateDebut" value="#{etpBean.dateDebut}" required="true">
                            <p:ajax listener="#{etpBean.listenerDateDebut}" event="change"/>
                        </p:calendar>
```

And here is my function in my bean

```
public Date listenerDateDebut(){
    return dateDebut;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value Change listner not working in primefaces calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099478/value-change-listner-not-working-in-primefaces-calendar)

Comment: but DateSelectEvent have been removed in primefaces 6.0 :/ :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [PrimeFaces 6 documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf):

> ### Ajax Behavior Events
>
> Calendar provides a `dateSelect` ajax behavior event to execute an instant ajax selection whenever a date is selected. If you define a method as a listener, it will be invoked by passing an `org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent` instance.
>
> ```
> <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date}">
>     <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.handleDateSelect}" update="msg" />
> </p:calendar>
> <p:messages id="msg" />
> ```
>
> ```
> public void handleDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
>     Date date = (Date) event.getObject();
>     //Add facesmessage
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm going to investigate why the original question does not work. I'd expect it to just work (or the listener is not being called at all due to a wrong method signature

Comment: And as a matter of fact, this is also (sort of) in the original link you referred to as a 'single' upvoted answer...., just a different event... All kind of weird AND even more identical as a non-upvoted answer... Maybe we should mark this one as a duplicate and improve the other one

Comment: Oh, you modified the answer of the other question... I thought you meant this one.... hahaha... Sorry...